# join command leaving out a row of numbers

Tags: bash, shell, join

I have two files, I want to take out the rows which have common data in the third column. But it is leaving out a row which should be matched.

File1

```
b b b
4 5 3
c c c
```

File2

```
1 2 3 4
a b c d
e f g h
i j k l
l m n o
```

The output is:

```
c c c a b d
```

The command used is:

```
join -1 3 -2 3 --nocheck-order File1.txt File2.txt
```

It is missing out the row with 3 as the common field, even after placing the --nocheck-order

Edit:

Expected output:

```
c c c a b d
3 4 5 1 2 4
```

Comment: The `join` commands requires its inputs sorted on the join key.  Your `File1.txt` is not sorted on the third column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to 2 `sort` commands (can be very expensive for big files) and then a `join`, you can use this single `awk` command to get your output:

```
awk 'FNR == NR{a[$3]=$0; next} $3 in a{print $3, a[$3], $1, $2, $4}' file1 file2

3 4 5 3 1 2 4
c c c c a b d
```

**Explanation:**

```
NR == FNR {                  # While processing the first file
  a[$3] = $0                 # store the whole line in array a using $3 as key
  next
}

$3 in a {                    # while processing the 2nd file, when $3 is found in array
  print $3,a[$3],$1,$2,$4    # print relevant fields from file2 and the remembered
                             # value from the first file.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to sort your inputs (e.g. using [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution)):

```
$ join -1 3 -2 3 <(sort -k3 1.txt) <(sort -k3 2.txt)
3 4 5 1 2 4
c c c a b d
```

This is equivalent to:

```
$ sort -k3 1.txt > 1-sorted.txt
$ sort -k3 2.txt > 2-sorted.txt
$ join -1 3 -2 3 1-sorted.txt 2-sorted.txt
3 4 5 1 2 4
c c c a b d
```

Comment: That does it, but shouldn't the --nocheck-order take care of that?

Comment: @BhavyaArora Nope, that just suppresses the checking that it does; it still assumes sorted input.  The idea is that if you *know* the input is sorted, you can gain some speed by not checking.

Comment: Is there a way to get the common elements from say third column without sorting. It increases the running time for my algorithm. Maybe some other command you can suggest.

Comment: though I am not knowledgeable with Bash scripting, I believe awk might be of help, but unfortunately I don't know much about it.